# Characteristic polynomial of $r \times r$ companion matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, cyclotomic-polynomials, companion-matrices

I want to show that $a(x) = \det[C(a)-x I]$ where $a(x)=a_0+ax+...+a_{r-1}x^{r-1}+x^r$ and $C(a)$ is the companion matrix:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
0&1&0&\dots& 0 \\
0&0&1&\dots& 0 \\
0&0&0&\dots& 0 \\
\vdots&&&&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\dots& 1\\
-a_0&-a_1&-a_2&\dots&-a_{r-1}
\end{vmatrix}$$

I've tried Laplace on this, and I sense that I need to reduce the final matrix in some triangular form, I'm little rusty in matrix algebra. 
Some hints?